Unable to query after a successful connection for a period of time in GridDB
I’m experiencing an issue with GridDB where the program becomes blocked during a query and logs a Sending heartbeat It seems that the issue is related to the connection management or the GridDB cluster's responsiveness
Following are the logs
select * where (name='message-count') AND count > 0 AND  timestamp < TIMESTAMP('2022-12-30T11:02:01.567+0800') AND timestamp > TIMESTAMP('2022-12-29T11:02:01.567+0800') order by timestamp
Sending heartbeat (statement=CREATE_SESSION, address=/192.168.1.134:10001, partition=7, statementId=15, elapsedMillis=10000)
Sending heartbeat (statement=CREATE_SESSION, address=/192.168.1.134:10001, partition=7, statementId=15, elapsedMillis=20004)

This may be a concurrency problem. I try the following code to reproduce this problem
package com.griddb.client;

import cn.hutool.core.date.DateField;
import cn.hutool.core.date.DateTime;
import cn.hutool.core.date.DateUtil;
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import static cn.hutool.core.date.DatePattern.UTC_MS_WITH_ZONE_OFFSET_PATTERN;


public class GriddbClient {
    static class Iot {
        @RowKey
        Date timestamp;
        double data;
        double temperature;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Iot{" +
                    "timestamp=" + timestamp +
                    ", data=" + data +
                    ", temperature=" + temperature +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //bulkInsertData();
        concurrentQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Bulk Insert Data
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void bulkInsertData() throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("host", "192.168.1.134");
        props.setProperty("port", "10001");
        props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
        props.setProperty("user", "admin");
        props.setProperty("password", "admin");
        props.setProperty("database","public");
        props.setProperty("transactionTimeout","5000");
        props.setProperty("failoverTimeout","5000");
        GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
        TimeSeries<test5.Iot> lctime = store.putTimeSeries("lctime", test5.Iot.class);
        lctime.createIndex("data");
        lctime.setAutoCommit(false);
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        for(int i=0;i<360;i++){
            DateTime dateTime = now.offset(DateField.MINUTE, 1);
            test5.Iot item1=new test5.Iot();
            item1.timestamp=dateTime;
            item1.data=i;
            item1.temperature=i;
            lctime.put(dateTime,item1);
            System.out.println(DateUtil.formatDateTime(dateTime));
        }



        lctime.commit();
        System.out.println("succcess");
        store.close();
    }

    /**
     * Concurrent query
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void concurrentQuery() throws Exception{
        int concurrency=10;
        final Date start=getDate("2022-11-20");
        final Date end=getDate("2022-12-30");
        Set<String> culume=new HashSet<String>();
        culume.add("timestamp");
        culume.add("data");
        culume.add("temperature");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("host", "192.168.1.134");
        props.setProperty("port", "10001");
        props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
        props.setProperty("user", "admin");
        props.setProperty("password", "admin");
        props.setProperty("database","public");
        props.setProperty("transactionTimeout","5000");
        props.setProperty("failoverTimeout","5000");
        final GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        List<FutureTask<List<test5.Iot>>> tasks=new ArrayList<FutureTask<List<test5.Iot>>>();

        for(int i=0;i<concurrency;i++){
            FutureTask<List<test5.Iot>> task1=new FutureTask<List<test5.Iot>>(new Callable<List<test5.Iot>>() {
                public List<test5.Iot> call() throws Exception {
                    return createTask(start,end,store);
                }
            });
            tasks.add(task1);
            executorService.submit(tasks.get(tasks.size()-1));
        }

        for(FutureTask<List<test5.Iot>> item:tasks){
            List<test5.Iot> iots = item.get();
            System.out.println(iots.size());
        }
        store.close();
    }

    private static List<test5.Iot> createTask(Date start, Date end, GridStore store) throws Exception{
        TimeSeries<test5.Iot> lctime = store.getTimeSeries("lctime", test5.Iot.class);
        String tql="select * where timestamp > TIMESTAMP('" + formatDate(start) + "') and timestamp < TIMESTAMP('" + formatDate(end) + "')";
        System.out.println(tql);
        RowSet<test5.Iot> query = lctime.query(tql, test5.Iot.class).fetch();
        List<test5.Iot> iots=new ArrayList<test5.Iot>();
        while (query.hasNext()){
            test5.Iot next = query.next();
            System.out.println(next.toString());
            iots.add(next);
        }
        lctime.close();
        return iots;
    }

    private static Date getDate(String dataStr) throws Exception{
        DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return dateFormat1.parse(dataStr);
    }

    private static String formatDate(Date date){
        return DateUtil.format(date,UTC_MS_WITH_ZONE_OFFSET_PATTERN);
    }
}

